# PHP Count occurance of 2 lists of words appear string

Tags: php

I have two lists of words. The idea is to count how many times each word appears in an article, then calculate the difference.

Example:

```
List1 = "how, now, brown, cow"
List2 = "he, usually, urges, an, umbrella, upon, us"
```

> Content: "How can I buy a cow when the umbrella is cheaper?"

Result: `List1(2) - List2(1) = 1`

I have fairly noobish PHP skills.

Comment: You can use `in_array` http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: How `List2(1)`? Shouldnt it be `List2(2)`?

Comment: in list2 you have umbrella and an so,list2=2.

Comment: Apologies, fixed the "an" to "the" to make it more obvious what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Your Question is Pretty Unclear. Please elaborate what you want to achieve over here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, we can use the Php functions [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and as [incognito-skull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3787519/incognito-skulll) mentioned, [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). You can do it by doing something like so:

```
$list1 = ['how', 'now', 'brown', 'cow'];
$list2 = ['he', 'usually', 'urges', 'an', 'umbrella', 'upon', 'us'];

$timesAList1WordAppeared = 0;
$timesAList2WordAppeared = 0;

$text = "how can I buy a cow when the umbrella is cheaper?";
$wordArray = explode(' ', $text);

foreach ($wordArray as $word) {
    if (in_array($word, $list1)) {
        $timesAList1WordAppeared++;
    }

    if (in_array($word, $list2)) {
        $timesAList2WordAppeared++;
    }
}

echo "The difference is: ".($timesAList1WordAppeared - $timesAList2WordAppeared);
```

Let's go at it step by step

At first, we initialize the array and counter variables

```
$list1 = ['how', 'now', 'brown', 'cow'];
$list2 = ['he', 'usually', 'urges', 'an', 'umbrella', 'upon', 'us'];

$timesAList1WordAppeared = 0;
$timesAList2WordAppeared = 0;
```

Then, we initialize the text

```
$text = "how can I buy a cow when the umbrella is cheaper?";
```

Then, we *split* this text using a space to get the words. This is where the `explode` function comes in and we use it like so

```
$wordArray = explode(' ', $text);
```

The first argument is the character or string we will use to split the text and the second argument is the text itself. Then we go through our words and count how many times a word in our `list1` and `list2` appears in the text. We do it like so

```
foreach ($wordArray as $word) {
    if (in_array($word, $list1)) {
        $timesAList1WordAppeared++;
    }

    if (in_array($word, $list2)) {
        $timesAList2WordAppeared++;
    }
}
```

The code goes like this, for each `word` in our `wordArray`, if that `word` is `in_[the]_array` `list1`, increment the `timesAList1WordAppeared`. If that `word` is also `in_[the]_array` `list2`, increment the `timesAList2WordAppeared`.

Lastly is to print the result

```
echo "The difference is: ".($timesAList1WordAppeared - $timesAList2WordAppeared);
```